# How you find the degree of a polynomial functions?

Tags: functions, polynomials

[image: Graph of polynomial functions]

How do you find the degree of a polynomial function? I know I have to find the turning points. But how do I find turning point on the graph? For example $y = (1-x)^2 \, (1+x)$. It has multiple interception.

Comment: What do you mean by the degree of a polynomial?  Most people would say it was the highest power of $x$ which appears, but you seem to have something else in mind.

Comment: The degree of the polynomial is just the largest power of $x$

Comment: I think I learned that I have to find the minimum turning point. By that I have to find all turning point and add them by 1.

Comment: Simple way to find degree is the largest power of x. Number of turning point <=degree-1. There may be repeat turning points. e.g. $y=x^4$, degree is 4 but only turning point is on $x=0$. You can count how many times it repeat, but then it will be troublesome.

Comment: The image here suggests that you need to find a polynomial which goes through some points, but these are not "turning points". "Turning points" are the points where the graph stops going down and starts going up, or vice-versa.

Comment: Lowest order equation equals lowest degree equation right?

Comment: Yes, in this case you need to find cubic equations (ones with x^3 terms) which go through the points in the graph.

Comment: y=-4(x+2)(x-1)(x-4) ?

Comment: Since these polynomials have three roots (zeros), their degrees must be at least $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +a_1x+a_0$, then the *degree* of $p$ is $n$.

So in your example it's $3$.

You can multiply it out,  or just note that the "highest power term" is going to be $3$.

---

I guess since the derivative will have degree $n-1$, and hence at most $n-1$ zeros,  you can count such points (with multiplicity) and add $1$, but this seems a lugubrious way of going about it.

Comment: As you can see in the picture, It says order. But order is degree right?

Comment: I hadn't seen the picture yet.   But, pretty clear it means degree.   And you can count the number of places where the derivative is zero  and add one, to do this problem.   You could also just count the $x$-intercepts.